# Liferay- folder level permissions in documents and media portlet

Tags: liferay

I have created two users -

- user1 and user2 in liferay portal and assigned separate role to each
  users by creating a new role.
- Also created two folders say test1 and test2 in documents and media
  portlet.
- I have granted permissions on these folders like user1 can view test1
  folder & user2 can view test2 folder.

Problem I'm facing is whenever I upload documents to these folders I'm not able to see the document when I logged in as user1 or user2.

But if I logged in as administrator files are visible.

anyone suggest me on this.

Comment: can you show your code

Comment: i'm trying this functionality through liferay gui only.

Comment: Would you also please include the version of Liferay under which you are developing.

Comment: I tried with both of these versions liferay-portal-6.2-ee-sp5 and liferay-portal-src-6.2-ce-ga2. even though its not working.

Comment: What user did you use to upload the files? Check the permissions on the individual files to see what roles have view capabilities. As far as I know, uploaded files will not inherit the permissions of a parent folder, thus you would have to manually assign the view permission of each uploaded file to the appropriate role. Another option would be to write a service hook that will force the permission inheritance.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion @Origineil. I will try your option n let  you know.

Comment: @siva Well? How did it go?